# Joining column values in a table - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have table following like

```
mark     name total  point
 70     bala   100    10
 80     bala   100    10
 80     bala   100    10
100  karthik   100     5
100  karthik   150     5
100  karthik   150     5
50     abdul   80     10
50     abdul   80      5
50     abdul   80      6
```

i want to split this table following (remove duplicate column based on name and unique column will be seperated by comma )

```
mark      name     total    point
70,80     bala     100        10
100       karthik  100,150     5
50        abdul    80       10,5,6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
In [858]: (df.astype(str).groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)
             .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({v: ','.join(x[v].unique()) for v in x})))
Out[858]:
    mark     name    total   point
0  70,80     bala      100      10
1    100  karthik  100,150       5
2     50    abdul       80  10,5,6
```

Or,

```
In [863]: (df.astype(str).groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)
             .apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))))
Out[863]:
    mark     name    total   point
0  70,80     bala      100      10
1    100  karthik  100,150       5
2     50    abdul       80  10,5,6
```

Comment: We can also do that in pivot table. So we can save lot of parameters :). And +1 for maintaining the order.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(index='name',aggfunc=lambda x : ','.join(x.unique().astype(str))).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    name   mark   point    total
0    abdul     50  10,5,6       80
1     bala  70,80      10      100
2  karthik    100       5  100,150
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = (df.astype(str)
       .groupby('name', as_index=False, sort=False)
       .agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique())))
print (df)
      name   mark    total   point
0     bala  70,80      100      10
1  karthik    100  100,150       5
2    abdul     50       80  10,5,6
```